# What's the idiomatic way in go to return optional interface values?

Tags: go

Imagine I have some types and an interface:

```golang
type Foo struct {}

type Bar struct {}

type Stuff interface {
  IsStuff()
}

func (_ Foo) IsStuff() {}
func (_ Bar) IsStuff() {}
```

Now imagine I have a function that may return `Stuff` or nothing.

```golang
func FindStuff() ??? {
 // ...
}
```

If the return type was a normal struct I could just return a pointer to the struct and return `nil` inside the function.
But using pointer to interfaces seems to be frowned upon in Go (and it's also tricky to find if the interface is nil).

So how to define `FindStuff`?

Comment: An interface can be nil. Don't return a pointer to an interface, just return the interface. All sorts of functions only return the `error` interface and the first thing every dev knows to do is check if its nil. No difference here.

Comment: Every function that returns `error` does this. You return `nil` when there's no value to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the interface, it allows you to return `nil`:

```
func FindStuff() Stuff {
    return nil
}
```

[Working example](https://go.dev/play/p/vBaZJFQFvmY)